# Cannot find FindOne method in MongoDB C# driver 2.2.2

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to compile following code

```
var database = blogContext.Client.GetDatabase("dbName");
var collection = database.GetCollection<Post>("collectionName");
var recentPosts = await blogContext.Posts.FindOne()
```

...

However compiler throws an error that FindOne() method does not exists, which should I guess.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

`FindOne` is not supported  in  the new driver  which support the async pattern of .net

if you want to  use such functionality you have to  install the legacy mongocsharpdriver from  nuget

```
Install-Package mongocsharpdriver
```

which is different from

```
Install-Package MongoDB.Driver
```

The legacy driver is no more recommended as the new driver using options classes for optional parameters so that we don't need  multiple overloads of methods and for this reason you have for example   `FindOneAndDelete()` which cannot be found in the  legacy driver

for more info

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-20-net-driver